# How to schedule WorkManager for when app is not in foreground

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to run a task which makes some API calls and does changes to the local db. This should not happen while the app is running else it will wreak havoc.

How I can set the workManager to execute to when the app is not in the foreground?

I see that there's a `setRequiresDeviceIdle(boolean)` method which seems like the closest fit, but its unfortunately not available below API 23 and there's no recourse to that.

What are my options to achieve this?

Comment: Would it work if you set the Work to execute in `onPause` and cancel it `onResume`?

Comment: That actually might work. Thank you for that suggestion @jackz314

Answer (score -1):

You can run a schedule and then can check if app is running or not. If app is running then do not call the api else call. For checking app is running or not use the below method

```
public static boolean isAppRunning(final Context context, final String packageName) {
            final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (procInfos != null)
            {
                for (final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : procInfos) {
                    if (processInfo.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: My app supports API 16 onwards so I cannot use JobScheduler. In any case, WM already uses JobScheduler internally. The alternative would have been Firebase job scheduler, but that is deprecated now in favor or WorkManager.

Comment: Would you please check my second approach.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sultan. I can use this check. Thats not the problem. The problem still is that the work or schedule needs to execute when the app is not in foreground. Else this condition will keep failing and the work will never execute.

Comment: Without service you can not check app is running or not . So within service you need to check it. Suppose every 30 minutes later service will check your app status and then will run the api call .Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thats a very bad solution. If you know how Doze mode, app standby, app standby buckets work and are aware of Huawei, Samsung and other OEMs aggressive background processes curtailing you'll know that triggering a component to run every 30 minutes is a very bad idea. Thats the whole reason why WorkManager and JobScheduler was built.